# class for convert wav 2 mp3 in java

Tags: java, audio, mp3, wav

is there a class for convert wav 2 mp3 in java

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [LAMEOnJ](http://openinnowhere.sourceforge.net/lameonj/)?